# Overflow error when inserting decimal into SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting the error `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.` in MS SQL. Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Percentages]
(
    [enabled] bit,
    [name] nvarchar(150),
    [percent] decimal(5,5)
)
```

And here's what I'm trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO [Percentages] ([enabled], [name], [percent])
VALUES (1,'Test',2.0)
```

If the decimal limit is 00000.00000 to 99999.99999 then why is 2.0 giving me the error? "2" gives the same error as well

Comment: (5,5) means 5 digits in total, and 5 of those as decimals. (I.e. from -0.99999 to 0.99999.) You want `decimal(10,5)`.

Comment: Great to know, thanks! Feel free to add that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decimal(5,5)` means 5 digits in total, and 5 of those are decimals. (I.e. from -0.99999 to 0.99999.)

You want `decimal(10,5)`!

Answer (score 0):

Decimal(5,5) depicts - Decimal(p,s) in which `s` is the `scale`, number of digits right to the decimal point. `p` is the `precision` , total number of digits to be stored in decimal. Subtracting s from p gives the number of digits to the left of decimal point.

In your case - Decimal(5,5) allows 0 digits to the left of decimal point. Hence it throws an error.

Try giving : `decimal(10,5)` or other value based on your maximum expected value.